# Booting kernel from SD in qemu (ARM) with u-boot

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, qemu, u-boot

I'm quite new to embedded systems and I'm playing around with ARM on qemu. So I've run into problem booting linux kernel image from an emulated SD on versatile express with cpu cortex-a9.

I prepared everything in the following order: first, I've built the kernel with `vexpress_defconfig` using appropriate ARM toolchain. Then I've built u-boot with `vexpress_ca9x4_defconfig`. Everything went just fine. The linux kernel source I took is at version 4.13 (latest stable from git). U-boot version is 2017.09-00100. Then I prepared an SD image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=sd.img bs=4096 count=4096
mkfs.vfat sd.img
mount sd.img /mnt/tmp -o loop,rw
cp kernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage /mnt/tmp
umount /mnt/tmp
```

Next I try to run qemu as follows:

```
qemu-system-arm -machine vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9 -m 128M -dtb kernel/arch/arm/boot/dts/vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -kernel uboot/u-boot -sd sd.img -nographic
```

U-boot loads successfully and gives me command prompt. And SD is really there and attached:

```
=> mmcinfo
Device: MMC
Manufacturer ID: aa
OEM: 5859
Name: QEMU! 
Tran Speed: 25000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 1.0
High Capacity: No
Capacity: 16 MiB
Bus Width: 1-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
```

I attempt to load compressed image from SD into memory and boot it:

```
fatload mmc 0:0 0x4000000 zImage
```

and everything looks ok

```
=> fatload mmc 0:0 0x4000000 zImage
reading zImage
3378968 bytes read in 1004 ms (3.2 MiB/s)
```

but then I want to boot the kernel and get an error:

```
=> bootz 0x4000000
Bad Linux ARM zImage magic!
```

I also tried U-boot images, crafted with u-boot's `mkimage`, like in this example:

```
uboot/tools/mkimage -A arm -C none -O linux -T kernel -d kernel/arch/arm/boot/Image -a 0x00010000 -e 0x00010000 uImage
```

also trying out `-C gzip` on `zImage` and different load/entry addresses, to no avail. The images were copied to `sd.img`. When I `fatload` the image and check it with `iminfo`, whichever options I try, I constantly get error:

```
=> iminfo 0x4000000

## Checking Image at 04000000 ...
Unknown image format!
```

I'm totally confused and this problem drives me nuts, while information on this subject in Internet is rather scarce. Please, hint me what I'm doing wrong and redirect into right direction.

qemu in use is `QEMU emulator version 2.9.0`.

Comment: Seem like every image verification in RAM fails.  Are you sure you are using the proper address space where RAM actually exists?

Comment: @sawdust indeed, if I increase memory size to 256-512M, I can `fatload` compressed kernel image at 0x60000000 and `bootz` it. So this is fixed trivially. But what's interesting, I took a look at u-boot's `include/configs/versatile_common.h` and if I get it right, u-boot expects kernel to be loaded at 0x80008000. The range 0x80000000-0x84000000 is in turn remapped to first 64M of DRAM, at least according to [this](https://developer.arm.com/products/system-design/development-boards/soft-macro-models/docs/dui0448/latest/3-programmers-model/32-daughterboard-memory-map).

Comment: There's also address `kernel_addr=0x44100000` in u-boot's source. It looks like it falls into NOR/SRAM area. Is it supposed to be flashed with kernel/TPL on a real board? The memory layout is somewhat difficult to grasp, tbh. It looks unusual to me.

Comment: *"The range 0x80000000-0x84000000 is in turn remapped to first 64M of DRAM"* -- No, you're misreading that. In these ARM SoCs, only a portion of the address space is defined for RAM, e.g. DDR2 DRAM.   It looks like the 64MB at 0x0 can be remapped from 0x80000000; usually there's ROM at 0x0.  The remap would likely be used only for booting.  I see address space defined for two banks of RAM, at 0x60000000 and 0x80000000.

Comment: Aha, I see. So much to learn here, huh. Thank you very much for help.

Comment: Wow, I've been trying to do this kind of thing since yesterday and your question seems to be a good reference itself! Thank you!